# Send $(this) as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to send "this"(element fired) as parameter to the function, the function received "Object[Document build.php]" as arguments instead of the element fired.
Please let me know my fault:

```
function set(arg) {
    var element = arg.data.param;
    console.log(element);
}
$(".build_icon_container").on("mouseenter", {param: $(this)}, set);
```

Comment: $(this) will only work when its used in valid scope. Given your code example it is hard to tell if this is the case. Anyway, if you want to use `this` you must understand that it will refer to the object whose scope you're currently in - which can be an element or a function.

Comment: This as you show us will only return window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you are trying to execute `$(this)`, `this` doesn't refer to the element(s) you are binding the event handler to.

It's much simpler:

`this` inside the event handler will already refer to the correct element:

```
function set(event) {
    console.log(this);
}

$(".build_icon_container").on("mouseenter", set);
```

jQuery has a nice set of tutorials regarding event handling: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.